# Android unable to open file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-install-apk

i installed android studio in my window 8.

when i open it..it shows

> Unable to create temporary folder: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

please help me to find the solution

Comment: just try to create one directory in c:/ if it is created then there is not issue else if give error then you have to give permission

Answer (score 2):

I guess this will help you,
Whenever you wanna  launch your Android Studio or SDK manager, just try to right clicking on the .exe file of it and selecting as "Run As Administrator".
Make sure you have writing permissions

Answer (score 0):

Windows has serious issue with long file path .. so as @Mahesh Giri, set Android studio in c:/ or on top of any driver and launch normally .Try to avoid administrative privileges as much as you can.
Hope that may help.